# JSP, Spring MVC page redirect

Tags: spring, jsp, tomcat6

need your help on following error.

I am trying redirect to a second page from index.jsp using Spring MVC. But getting this error.

```
HTTP Status 404 - /redirect.do
description The requested resource is not available.
```

My controller class is,

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class MainInvController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/redirect")// , method = RequestMethod.GET
    @ResponseBody
    public String redirect() {
        System.out.println("redirect");
        return "bravo";
    }
}
```

Controller just try to redirect the user request to second page.

And my web.xml is

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Sample Inventory App</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/spring-master.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>invsample</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfiguration</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/invsample-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>invsample</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>     
</web-app>
```

invsample-servlet.xml as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

spring-master.xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">



    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>

    <!-- Load everything except @Controllers -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

index.jsp is given below.

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<h2>Spring Page Redirection</h2>
<p>Click below button to redirect the result to new page</p>
<form method="GET" action="/redirect.do">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="submit" value="Redirect Page"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return "bravo";` 
will not redirect(I hope when you said redirect you thought to have HTTP 302). It will try to find view relative to your current path(and reproduce HTTP 200 if success).

For redirect you should use

```
return "redirect:bravo"
```

But first you have an error in your jsp file.

```
<form method="GET" action="/redirect.do">
```

should be changed to

```
<form method="GET" action="/redirect">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Still getting the error                                                                                    HTTP Status 404 - /redirect
type Status report
message /redirect
description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: It loads the index page and when I clicked the "Redirect Page" button, this issue comes.

Comment: When started, index.jsp loaded from "http://localhost:8080/SpringTestINV/" and click on "Redirect Page" button goes to "http://localhost:8080/redirect" giving above error.

Comment: OK. That means that your controller is most probably not created in Spring context. try to change <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample"> to <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.*">

Comment: And yes Josh Ghiloni is right you need to remove @ResponseBody .

Comment: Controller getting created. But when I pressed "Redirect Page' button, above error comes with url "http://localhost:8080/redirect?". Then I tried "http://localhost:8080/SpringTestINV/redirect.do" by manually typing. Then it loads the second page. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, you need to remove the `@ResponseBody` annotation, so that Spring recognizes the return value as the name of a `View`, not a `String` that should be returned directly to the client.

Comment: Still didn't work. Getting the error as  "HTTP Status 404 - /redirect type Status report message /redirect description The requested resource is not available.". It loads home page which is index.jsp and when I clicked "Redirect Page" button, issue comes.

Comment: It is correct @ResponseBody has to be removed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to the index.jsp and it will do the redirection to /redirect which need to be captured in the controller class.

**JSP:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<body>
<c:redirect url="/redirect"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**Spring Controller:**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public void doGet() throws IOException { 
 // add logic here
 }
```